# Is there an R function that can execute the following conditions?

Tags: r, mutate

Is it possible to create a new dataframe based on the following conditions:

1. keep only all the values <=600
2. keep the value immediately following the last 'retained' value in a row (even if it does not meet the <=600 cutoff)

Input:

```
    1.  2.  3.   4.    5.    6.
A1. 60. 87. 98.  156.  289.  601
A2. 80. 97. 201. 325.  701.  800
A3. 95. 98. 324. 567.  650.  901
```

Output:

```
    1.  2.  3.   4.    5.    6.
A1. 60. 87. 98.  156.  289.  601
A2. 80. 97. 201. 325.  701.  NA
A3. 95. 98. 324. 567.  650.  NA
```

The values I do not want would be returned NA and in the above example, col.6 row A2 (800) and col.6 row A3 (901) were turned NA because they did not meet the condition of being <=600 and were not the value immediately following the last 'retained' value. But, for example, values 701 & 650 (col 5 row A2, A3 respectively) were kept because even though they did not meet the condition of being <=600, they were the values immediately following the last 'retained' value.

My code so far to mutate original data based on the <=600 conditions is as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)

newdata <- orginaldata|>mutate(across(everything(), \(x)
            if_else(between(x,0,601),x,NA)))
```

Comment: Why row A1 col6 does not return `NA`? 601 is clearly not <= 600

Comment: because even though it is not <=600, it is the value immediately following the last value that meets the <=600 cutoff

Comment: So you're doing it row-wise instead of column-wise? If that's the case, I think it's better to include it in the question itself because it's more common to use a column-wise approach in dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can first transpose the dataframe, then compare whether the previous values in the column is smaller than 600 or not. If so, retain the values, otherwise set `NA`. Finally transpose it back to the original format.

```r
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(t(df)) |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(lag(.x, default = 1) <= 600, .x, NA))) |> 
  t()

    1. 2.  3.  4.  5.  6.
A1. 60 87  98 156 289 601
A2. 80 97 201 325 701  NA
A3. 95 98 324 567 650  NA
```

#### Input data

```r
df <- structure(list(`1.` = c(60, 80, 95), `2.` = c(87, 97, 98), `3.` = c(98, 
201, 324), `4.` = c(156, 325, 567), `5.` = c(289, 701, 650), 
    `6.` = c(601L, 800L, 901L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A1.", 
"A2.", "A3."))
```